# Yii2 динамический роутинг

Tags: php, yii2

Есть нужда реализовать адреса страниц следующим образом:

**/admin/{project_id}/{controller}/{action}**

я пытался переопределить **Url::to**, чтобы при существовании **project_id** он добавлял в Get параметр значение **['project_id' => 12]**. и далее в main.php следующее правило роутинга

**'<project_id:\w+>/{controller:\w+}/{action:\w+}' => '/'**

но такой вариант ограничен. Например: Есть у меня кнопка Html::a('text', ['create']) и таких кнопок много. по текущей реализации мне придется во всех кнопках дописывать ['create', 'project_id' => 12], но это займет время.

Есть ли какая-то возможно реализовать данную возможность более корректным образом?

Answer (score 1):

Отнаследуйте Url, и допишите свой метод, аля

```php
public static function toProject(string $url,int $projectId,bool $scheme = false): string
{
    return self::to($url,$scheme,['xxx' => $projectId]);
}
```